# Can't get discount.rate function to calculate rate of return

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the discount.rate function in the package FinCal to calculate the rate of return and it doesn't seem to work for me.

```
discount.rate(n=360,pv=-100000,fv=0,pmt=500,type=0)
```

`n=360` means there are 360 payments (in other words, a 30 year loan)

`pv=` present value (meaning the bank gives a borrower $100,000 to purchase a home)

`pmt` = monthly payment

`fv` = future value (set to 0 because bank gives $100,000 initially but after 30 years receives nothing back except for the monthly mortgage payments)

`type` = 0 means that payments are made at the end of each period

I get the following error:

```
*Error in uniroot(function(r) fv.simple(r, n, pv) + fv.annuity(r, n, pmt,  : 
f.upper = f(upper) is NA*
```

I used the same values in a similar finance function in SAS and it worked fine.  Thanks for any help.

Per the suggestion of one user, I tried it in Excel and it worked fine also.  Works fine in SAS and Excel but not in R.

Comment: Please add four spaces before your code.

Comment: Are you sure  `FV = 0` is even possible given FV and PV relation and realistically which bank would provide a loan and be satisfied with just interest payments and not expect principal back at end of term. Try this in excel `=RATE(360,500,-100000,0,0)` and this [calculate I/Y](http://www.calculator.net/finance-calculator.html?ctype=returnrate&ctargetamountv=0&cyearsv=360&cstartingprinciplev=100000&cinterestratev=6&ccontributeamountv=500&ciadditionat1=end&printit=0&x=84&y=10)

Comment: I tried that in Excel and it worked for me.  I got .365559%.  I multiplied it by 12 to get a yearly rate and got 4.39%. The payment of $500 per period includes interest and principal.

Answer (score 0):

The FinCal package does not allow you to specify the compounding/discounting frequency (12 per year in this case) as an argument to the discount.rate() function and this seems to be causing an issue. If you convert pmt into per year (6,000 = 12*500) and set n=30 the function gives you 4.31%, which is the stated annual rate:

```
discount.rate(n=30, pv= -100000, fv=0, pmt=6000, type=0)
```

You then use the ear(r, m) function from the same package with m=12 and r=0.04306572 to get the Effective Annual Rate (EAR) of 4.39% :

```
ear(0.04306572,12)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It was caused by uniroot. The default interval in discount.rate() is (1e-10, 1e10), when I changed it to (1e-4, 1), I got 0.003683461.

> discount.rate(n=360,pv=-100000,fv=0,pmt=500,type=0,lower=0.0001, upper = 1)

[1] 0.003683461

I add two new parameters 'lower' and 'upper' to discount.rate() so you can try different intervals now. You need reinstall FinCal package.

library("devtools")
install_github("felixfan/FinCal") # from GitHub, now

or

install.packages("FinCal",dependencies=TRUE) # from CRAN, several days later

Comment: Thanks @felixfan.  Why did the larger interval (1e-10, 1e10) cause an error but the smaller interval (1e-4, 1) did not?

Comment: The function uniroot searches the interval from lower to upper for a root. I guess when the interval is large, the difference between any two tried root is large, the function does not converge. increase 'tol' or 'maxiter' may works for larger intervals, but the answer may be less accurate or it may take a longer time to search the right answer. see https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.3.3/topics/uniroot

Comment: @felixfan: I presume you are the package author. I am getting the same uniroot error. Did you reload the package on CRAN with those two added arguments as you mentioned? I donot see any new parameters in `discount.rate()` function yet.